# Azure yml pipeline being triggered on change to repository resource used for templates

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I currently have an Azure DevOps yaml file set up to release our project to its necessary environments. In this file, I reference a repository that holds our template files we use within the company.

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: 'Project/Repo'
    ref: 'refs/tags/x.x.x'

trigger: none
```

What is odd is that today I made a change to the template repository, and it triggered a build in all our pipelines that use this repository as a resource.  I have a trigger set to none, so why is it being triggered with a change to an outside repository?

Edit 1:

Adding an image to show some additional information
[image]

Comment: It is strange because this is opposite to what documentation says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers) `If you do not specify a trigger section in a repository resource, then the pipeline won't be triggered by changes to that repository. If you specify a trigger section, then the behavior for triggering is similar to how CI triggers work for the self repository.`

Comment: YES!  This is what is so frustrating, seems pretty clear to me that not specifying a trigger should prevent my exact issue. Perhaps I am dealing with a bug, however, I have to assume I am not the only one pulling in templates from another repository.

Comment: On UI what the trigger is?

Comment: There is no trigger set in the UI, its all via YAML files.

Comment: I mean what the type of trigger you see on the list where you see executed runs.

Comment: I see, added an image to help.  I don't see a specific trigger, like what configuration caused the trigger, just that the user who made the change is the one that triggered the run.